# javascript string to number = NaN

Tags: javascript

I am studying Javascript. Can someone please tell me what I'm not doing right?

```js
total = pdf_tp_summa+2490+(Number(elem_summa_sms.value))+(Number(elem_summa_push.value));
```

NaN total outputs in Console.

```
typeof(pdf_tp_summa) = number

typeof(elem_summa_sms.value) = string

typeof(elem_summa_push.value) = string
```

Comment: adding string in the number could you replace the string with actual value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is NaN. It is how javascript works.

```
//elem_summa_push.value is string, so 
Number(elem_summa_push.value)//eg. Number('asdf')
```

Would result in NaN.

And when you add any number to the NaN it would result NaN.

If the `elem_summa_push.value` is type of string but still contains number then it wouldn't result in NaN. For eg. `Number('234')`

Comment: forgot that added to the number in the symbol value "ք"

Comment: Yeah, which returns NaN.